# Why was Gale edited out of the propos in the movie version?

Tags: the-hunger-games, mockingjay

There were scenes where Katniss and Gale were filmed together (for example, shooting down the Capital planes in one of the early propos). However, when the propo is shown to District 13, only Katniss is shown shooting down the planes; given that he was standing right next to her at the time, Gale seems to have been completely edited out.

In the propo describing what they did to District 13, Gale's commentary on the event seems to have been completely omitted (unless I'm mistaken).

Why were these omitted, especially given that Gale was widely believed to be her cousin (or, at least, that's the story that was disseminated)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Katniss is the face of the revolution. Gale is just some hunky-looking guy.**

The propos featuring Katniss are all about showing *her* off to the audience. She's the one who can inspire the population; they don't know Gale, and his presence there might confuse them or make them wonder unnecessarily. **A propaganda message is most effective when it's kept simple.** You want to advertise Katniss to fire up the rebellion? Fine, advertise Katniss. Don't let some other guy take up half the screen, even if some of the viewers might remember who he is. You don't want people thinking, "who's that guy? oh, right, he's her brother or cousin or something from District 12"; you want them thinking, "Mockingjay! YEAH! Go girl on fire!" and getting inspired.

In fact, you could as easily ask the same question about out-of-universe advertising. Why do the posters for the Hunger Games films tend to show Katniss alone in the middle? Because she's the main character, that's why. Why aren't there any film posters with a picture of Katniss next to Mitchell? Because who the hell is Mitchell and why should he be advertised next to the main character, that's why. (I chose Mitchell instead of Gale because Gale is important in the *story* - probably as many random viewers in Panem remember Gale as random viewers in the real world remember Mitchell.)